# No Ice Candidates gathering, peerConnection.iceGatheringState returns "complete" right away

Tags: reactjs, firebase, webrtc

I've been stuck on this for a while now. My code is based on https://webrtc.org/getting-started/firebase-rtc-codelab. I basically just changed it to React and firebase realtime database instead of firestore.

```
const VideoRoom = () => {
  const config = {
    apiKey: xxx,
    authDomain: xxx,
    databaseURL: xxx,
    projectId: xxx,
    storageBucket: xxx,
    messagingSenderId: xxx,
    appId: xxx,
  };

  const rtcconfig = {
    iceServers: [
      {
        urls: [
          "stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302",
          "stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302",
        ],
      },
    ],
    iceCandidatePoolSize: 10,
  };

  const { roomId } = useParams();

  if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
  }

  const db = firebase.database();
  const rooms = () => db.ref("rooms");
  const room = (roomId) => db.ref(`rooms/${roomId}`);
  const callerCandidates = (roomId) =>
    db.ref(`rooms/${roomId}/callerCandidates`);
  const calleeCandidates = (roomId) =>
    db.ref(`rooms/${roomId}/calleeCandidates`);

  const peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(rtcconfig);
  var localStream = new MediaStream();
  var remoteStream = null;

  var localVideo = useRef(null);
  var remoteVideo = useRef(null);

  room(roomId)
    .once("value")
    .then((snapshot) => {
      if (!snapshot.val()) {
        createRoom();
        return;
      }
      joinRoomById(roomId, snapshot.val());
    });

  useEffect(() => {
    peerConnection.addEventListener("icegatheringstatechange", () => {
      console.log(
        `ICE gathering state changed: ${peerConnection.iceGatheringState}`
      );
    });

    peerConnection.addEventListener("connectionstatechange", () => {
      console.log(`Connection state change: ${peerConnection.connectionState}`);
    });

    peerConnection.addEventListener("signalingstatechange", () => {
      console.log(`Signaling state change: ${peerConnection.signalingState}`);
    });

    peerConnection.addEventListener("iceconnectionstatechange ", () => {
      console.log(
        `ICE connection state change: ${peerConnection.iceConnectionState}`
      );
    });
  });

  const createRoom = async () => {
    console.log("create room");
    localStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
      console.log("adding localStream to peerConnection");
      peerConnection.addTrack(track, localStream);
    });

    peerConnection.addEventListener("icecandidate", (event) => {
      console.log("listening for icecandidate on peerConnection");
      if (!event.candidate) {
        console.log("final icecandidate");
        return;
      }
      console.log("callerCandidate written to database");
      callerCandidates(roomId).set(event.candidate.toJSON());
    });

    const offer = await peerConnection.createOffer();
    await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
    console.log("Offer created and added to peerConnection local description");

    const roomWithOffer = {
      offer: {
        type: offer.type,
        sdp: offer.sdp,
      },
    };

    await room(roomId).update(roomWithOffer);
    console.log("Offer written to room database document");

    peerConnection.addEventListener("track", (event) => {
      event.streams[0].getTracks().forEach((track) => {
        console.log(
          "listening for track on peerConnection and adding them to remoteStream"
        );
        remoteStream.addTrack(track);
      });
    });

    room(roomId).on("value", async (snapshot) => {
      console.log("listening for remote session in room database document");
      const data = snapshot.val();
      if (!peerConnection.currentRemoteDescription && data && data.answer) {
        console.log("Got remote description: ", data.answer);
        const rtcSessionDescription = new RTCSessionDescription(data.answer);
        await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(rtcSessionDescription);
      }
    });

    calleeCandidates(roomId).on("value", (snapshot) => {
      console.log(
        "listening for remote ICE candidates in room/calleCandidates database document"
      );
      if (snapshot.val()) {
        snapshot.val().forEach(async (change) => {
          if (change.type === "added") {
            let data = change.doc.data();
            await peerConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(data));
          }
        });
      }
    });
  };
};
```

I'm getting the roomId through react router, I left out the rest of the component for the sake of readability.

The console returns following:

create room
Signaling state change: have-local-offer
Offer created and added to peerConnection local description
ICE gathering state changed: complete
listening for icecandidate on peerConnection
final icecandidate
adding localStream to peerConnection
Offer written to room database document
listening for remote ICE candidates in room/calleCandidates database document
listening for remote session in room database document

In the about:webrtc firefox tab I can see that the offer was created succesfully but there arent any ice candidates

Thanks in advance!

Comment: BTW, I've found your question by searching the exact same phrase on Google :)

Answer (score 5):

So, turns out ICE Candidates gathering only start when some track is added to the stream, and that MUST be done BEFORE the offer creation.

So if you gather the media and add it to the RTCPeerConnection instance BEFORE creating the offer, then you'll see ICE candidates being gathered properly.

**EDIT:** Aside from this, If you provide the options upon offer creation like below, it will start ICE gathering as expected:

```
await this.connection.createOffer({
  offerToReceiveAudio: true,
  offerToReceiveVideo: true,
});
```

Hope it helps!